# How to get the result from bash auto-completion as a string?

Tags: command-line, bash, autocomplete, bash-scripting

What I'm looking for is not how to add autcompletion in bash for another program, but a way to get the result of what would have happened in bash to a string, basically:

```
autocomplete "/etc/apa"
```

would return

```
/etc/apache2/
```

so I can use that in my script.

Any help is greatly appreciated, for all I can find is how to use the "complete" bash function, which does something different ;)

Cheers,
rafael

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Bash` has a built-in command `compgen` which can help you a lot. For example, if you want to know which dirs would be auto-completed when you type `cd /etc/s<TAB>`:

```
$ compgen -d /etc/s
/etc/security
/etc/sgml
/etc/skel
/etc/ssh
/etc/ssl
/etc/subversion
/etc/sudoers.d
/etc/sysctl.d
$
```

Then, the following command would tell you which dir you'll go into by `cd /etc/se<TAB>`:

```
$ compgen -d /etc/se
/etc/security
$
```

`compgen` can take most options of the `complete` command. See [bash's manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins) for more details.